# Eclipse Syntax error on token "}", delete this token and Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error, java-10

I am trying to make a practice program for a bookstore clerk that allows the clerk to add, remove, edit, and search for books in its database. I have all but made the entire program however I am getting stuck on 2 errors. It is a total of 234 lines of code in all so I will try to shorten it to the relevant parts to make it easier on those willing to help me. I am using Eclipse with JDE and JDK 10. The Eclipse project was initiated using the JavaSE-10 execution environment as far as I am aware. Below are the 2 methods causing the errors.

```
public class Bookstore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(
                //Creating table connection and statement
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("***********",
                        "****", "*********"); //Please note that I blocked out the actual connection information here

                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int selection = 0;

            //Menu for action selection and user input
            while(selection != 5) {
                System.out.println("Please enter the number corresponding to the action you would like to take:\n"
                        + "1. Enter book\n"
                        + "2. Update book\n"
                        + "3. Delete book\n"
                        + "4. Search books\n"
                        + "5. Exit");
                selection = input.nextInt();

                //Selection sorting
                if(selection == 1) {
                    //Collecting book information
                    System.out.println("Please enter the Title of the book you would like to put into the system: ");
                    String title = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the Author of said book: ");
                    String author = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the number of said book currently in stock: ");
                    int qty = input.nextInt();

                    //Sending info to the addBook method
                    addBook(title, author, qty, stmt);
                } else if(selection == 2) {
                    //Collecting book information
                    System.out.println("Please enter the id of the book you would like to update: ");
                    int id = input.nextInt();

                    //Sending info to the updateBook method
                    updateBook(id, stmt);
                } else if(selection == 3) {
                    //Collecting book information
                    System.out.print("Please enter the id of the book you would like to delete from the system: ");
                    int id = input.nextInt();

                    //Sending info to deleteBook method
                    deleteBook(id, stmt);
                } else if(selection == 4) {
                    searchStore(stmt);
                } else if(selection == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    input.close();
                } else { //Invalid entry handler
                    System.out.println("Sorry, that isn't a valid selection.");
                }
            }

        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} //This is the line giving me the error "Syntax error on token "}", delete this token"
```

Now I have already done some research regarding the error at the bottom of this block of code. As far as I can tell I am not missing any brackets and there are no variables or anything being created outside of a class that would cause this error. The only other solution I have been able to find is that "Eclipse is just being weird".

My second error comes from this block of code:

```
public static void resultSetPrinter(ResultSet rset) {
    while(rset.next()) {
        String title = rset.getString("Title");
        String author = rset.getString("Author");
        int qty = rset.getInt("qty");
        System.out.println("Title: " + title + "\nAuthor: " + author + "\nNumber in stock: " + qty + "\n\n");
    }
    if(rset == null) {
        System.out.println("No records for the entry could be found.");
    }
} //This is the line giving me the "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody" error
```

I have also done some research regarding the error at the bottom of this block and when I do remove the bracket as requested the error just jumps up to the method before this one. I haven't included the other 4 methods in the class to try and reduce the headache of running through all this code since they aren't giving me errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point, I am completely stumped.

Comment: Do a CTRL+A, then a CTRL+SHIFT+F, this will format the code so that you should spot the point where something went wrong with your brackets or indentation.

Comment: Well `if` rset is null, you throw a nullpointerexception on `while(rset.next())` so the code doesn't make any sense. Finally, why are you closing the class and then trying to add a method?

Comment: @Marco13 So all CTRL+A and CTRL+SHIFT+F did was put my user selection lines onto 1 row which for me, because of how I enter commands into SQL via the command line, honestly just made it harder to read. Although I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I think the reason I originally put the methods outside the class was because I was getting SQLException handling errors. I went ahead and moved those into the method and put in the proper try catch lines and that seemed to correct all my issues. Regarding the rset == null section, I wanted to print out a message if my searching of the database didn't find anything, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks mainly to Elliott Frisch I have found my answer. Essentially I needed to put all my methods into my main class by the name of Bookstore. I moved the `}` to the end of my program and added try catch statements for each method. For example I changed the last code block I put in my question to:

```
public static void resultSetPrinter(ResultSet rset) {
    try {
        if(rset.next()) {
            while(rset.next()) {
                String title = rset.getString("Title");
                String author = rset.getString("Author");
                int qty = rset.getInt("Qty");
                System.out.println("Title: " + title + "\nAuthor: " + author + "\nNumber in stock: " + qty + "\n");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No records for the entry could be found.\n");
        }
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You'll also note that I added an if else statement to check if the ResultSet `rset` was empty, if it wasn't I proceeded as normal and if it was I printed a simple message to let the user know nothing was found.

Thank you both Elliott Frisch and Marco13 for the asssistance.